# How do I move .doc and .xls files to a new folder?

Tags: command-line, files

Situation: I finally convinced my dad to let me install Xubuntu on his desktop, since Windows XP had become extremely bloated, old - it's a mess. So I installed Xubuntu 12.10 alongside the Windows partition, and he wants me to move all his .doc and .xls files to the new partition before I erase the Windows partition.
This is easier said than done. My dad has subdirectories upon subdirectories, and I really don't want to have to manually go through every single folder to get all his documents and spreadsheets.

Question: How do I move all his .doc and .xls files to a new folder?

Additional Info: I know there are ways to move *all* files, but I only want to move files of a certain type (.doc, .xls). I've already tried `find "/media/gregory/Secondary/Documents and Settings/Gregory Davidson" -name '*.doc' | xargs -i cp /home/gregory/Documents`, but when I manually checked, it hadn't moved the documents in many, if not all, of the subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in the directory that you want to copy files from,

```
cp -r **/{*.doc,*.xls} /wherever/you/want/
```

would do the trick.

Comment: I forgot I would have to be in the original directory; Now I feel stupid :/
Thanks for the quick response!