# Remove files of certain type, retain directory tree

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to move a bunch of .doc and .xls files, which are stored in a bunch of folders and subfolders, to a new location. I previously tried `cp -r **/{*.doc,*.xls} /wherever/you/want/`, which worked except that it didn't retain the directory tree faster.

Question: Is there a command/set of commands to purge all files except for .doc and .xls in a folder and its subfolders, yet retain directory tree structure?
And better yet, is there a command to remove empty folders, so I don't have to go through afterwards and manually delete empty folders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `find` command. These commands are meant to be run from *inside* the directory where your .xls and .doc files (and other directories) are kept. DO NOT run this on your home directory!

The easiest way to do it is deleting all non-xls and non-doc files (CAREFUL, this command *will* delete all other files):

```
find ./ -type f -not -name "*.xls" -and -not -name "*.doc" -exec rm {} \;
```

Then you can use this to find and delete empty directories. To avoid using a potentially very destructive `rm -rf`, this deletes one level at a time, you may have to run it several times to delete all empty directories:

```
find ./ -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153172/how-can-i-use-find-command-more-efficiently/153184#153184) for more details on what find does and how to use it.

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS** - op used the word "purge" poorly; he's clearly trying to copy/move files, NOT delete them.

Comment: @JimSalter No, I meant removal of files that weren't .doc or .xls
This solution worked great for me, since it only kept .doc and .xls files, and kept the directory tree structure.
The empty folder remover was a little confusing to run, since it would always throw up "no file/directory" errors, but it *did* remove all the empty folders.

Comment: My bad - but then, I'm confused - why were you using the `cp` command in the original example?

Comment: That's alright. In [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220587/move-doc-and-xls-files-to-new-folder) I used that command, but it didn't keep the directory tree structure, it just dumped all the .docs and .xls's into the new folder. I was providing it just for more info.

Comment: Using `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;` is much better (you need to run it only once then). Besides, the `{}` should be quoted: `"{}"`

Answer (score 3):

This should do it all at once:

```
find path/to/dir '!' -iname "*.doc" '!' -iname "*.xls" -empty -delete
```

(Except your folders have extensions like `.xls` or `doc`...)

Replace `-delete` with `-print` to see what gets deleted first.

Answer (score 2):

This requires some fairly fancy rsync syntax, but it can be done:

```
rsync -r --filter="+ */" --filter="+ **/*.xls" --filter="+ **/*.doc" --filter="- **" --prune-empty-dirs /path/to/source/ /path/to/target/
```

Demonstration:

```
me@banshee:/tmp$ find source
source
source/1.xls
source/1
source/1/2
source/1/2/2.xls
source/1/1.doc
source/lol.crapfile

me@banshee:/tmp$ find target
target

me@banshee:/tmp$ rsync -r --filter="+ */" --filter="+ **/*.xls" --filter="+ **/*.doc" --filter="- **" --prune-empty-dirs source/ target/

me@banshee:/tmp$ find target
target
target/1.xls
target/1
target/1/2
target/1/2/2.xls
target/1/1.doc
```

Comment: **NOTE** - above copies the files from source to target while keeping directory structure intact; it does **not** remove them from the source (this is a copy operation, not a move operation).

Comment: **NOTE 2** - this answer's OP's first sentence **"I'm trying to move a bunch of .doc and .xls files, which are stored in a bunch of folders and subfolders, to a new location"**.  It does **not** answer OP's actual question, which was apparently just how to remove everything **but** those files after having copied the entire structure to a new location.

Comment: As a rule, it would be better to include these comments as an edit to your post